# How do I check a string, using python, against some specific ABNF rules?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I need to check a string if is in conformance with this rules: http://www.w3.org/TR/widgets/#zip-rel-path

```
Zip-rel-path   = [locale-folder] *folder-name file-name /
                 [locale-folder] 1*folder-name
locale-folder  = %x6C %x6F %x63 %x61 %x6C %x65 %x73
                 "/" lang-tag "/"
folder-name    = file-name "/"
file-name      = 1*allowed-char
allowed-char   = safe-char / zip-UTF8-char
zip-UTF8-char  = UTF8-2 / UTF8-3 / UTF8-4
safe-char      = ALPHA  / DIGIT / SP  / "$" / "%" / 
                 "'"    / "-"   / "_" / "@" / "~" /
                 "("    / ")"   / "&" / "+" / "," /
                 "="    / "["   / "]" / "."
UTF8-2         = %xC2-DF UTF8-tail
UTF8-3         = %xE0 %xA0-BF UTF8-tail / %xE1-EC 2( UTF8-tail ) /
                 %xED %x80-9F UTF8-tail / %xEE-EF 2( UTF8-tail )
UTF8-4         = %xF0 %x90-BF 2( UTF8-tail ) / %xF1-F3 3( UTF8-tail ) /
                 %xF4 %x80-8F 2( UTF8-tail )
UTF8-tail      = %x80-BF
lang-tag       = primary-subtag *( "-" subtag )
primary-subtag = 1*8low-alphasubtag         = 1*8(alphanum)
alphanum       = low-alpha  / DIGITlow-alpha      = %x61-7a
```

A code example exactly on the rules above would help,  I am not familiar with ABNF.
I don't need a way to parse the ABNF, I just need only the above rules translated manually by someone who is used to or understands ABNF, to python code with regular expressions or any other way. Practically just input a string and verify it against the above mentioned rules eventually as a function that enters a string and returns true or false if the rules are matched or not. So to put it in a form of a question: How would this look in implemented in python?

I see from the  UTF8 documentation that much of the part from the rules above is just checking if string is utf8:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629

```
UTF8-char   = UTF8-1 / UTF8-2 / UTF8-3 / UTF8-4
   UTF8-1      = %x00-7F
   UTF8-2      = %xC2-DF UTF8-tail
   UTF8-3      = %xE0 %xA0-BF UTF8-tail / %xE1-EC 2( UTF8-tail ) /
                 %xED %x80-9F UTF8-tail / %xEE-EF 2( UTF8-tail )
   UTF8-4      = %xF0 %x90-BF 2( UTF8-tail ) / %xF1-F3 3( UTF8-tail ) /
                 %xF4 %x80-8F 2( UTF8-tail )
   UTF8-tail   = %x80-BF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've attempted to write a parser for you.

I agree that the bulk is a test for UTF-8, which is redundant if you already have the value in a string (UTF-8 is the encoding on the file system, unicode is the internal representation of the *valid* UTF-8). That does indeed simplify things tremendously.

As I understand it, the BNF says:

- **locale-folder** (which is optional) is the string 'locale/' followed by **lang-tag**
- **lang-tag** is of the form 'en', 'en-us', 'en-123', 'en-us-1' and so on:

  - At least one token, separated by the '-' character
  - Each token is from 1 to 8 characters
  - The first token may have only lower case letters
  - Following tokens are a mix of lower case letters and numbers
- After the optional locale, you can have:

  - A single **file-name** or
  - A path (a series of **folder-name** separated by '/') or
  - A path followed by a **file-name**
- **folder-name** and **file-name** are sort-of unicode. Each character is either

  - A-Z, a-z, 0-9, or
  - Any of " $%'-_@~()&+,=[]."
  - Any character *above* u007F (the UTF8 two, three and four-byte characters)

That said, here is a simple implementation (For the purpose of debugging it captures the output from the parsing. I did this for debugging, but please feel free to remove this if you don't need it). Errors in the path cause the ZipRelPath constructor to raise a ValueError:

```
import re

class ZipRelPath:
    FILE_NAME_RE = re.compile(u"^[a-zA-Z0-9 \$\%\'\-_@~\(\)&+,=\[\]\.\u0080-\uFFFF]+$")
    LANG_TAG_RE  = re.compile("^[a-z]{1,8}(\-[a-z0-9]{1,8})*$")
    LOCALES      = "locales/"

    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path
        self.lang_tag = None
        self.folders = []
        self.file_name = None

        self._parse_locales()
        self._parse_folders()

    def _parse_locales(self):
        """Consumes any leading 'locales' and lang-tag"""
        if self.path.startswith(ZipRelPath.LOCALES):
            self.path = self.path[len(ZipRelPath.LOCALES):]
            self._parse_lang_tag()

    def _parse_lang_tag(self):
        """Parses, consumes and validates the lang-tag"""
        self.lang_tag, _, self.path = self.path.partition("/")
        if not self.path:
            raise ValueError("lang-tag missing closing /")
        if not ZipRelPath.LANG_TAG_RE.match(self.lang_tag):
            raise ValueError(u"'%s' is not a valid language tag" % self.lang_tag)

    def _parse_folders(self):
        """Handles the folders and file-name after the locale"""
        while (self.path):
            self._parse_folder_or_file()

        if not self.folders and not self.file_name:
            raise ValueError("Missing folder or file name")

    def _parse_folder_or_file(self):
        """Each call consumes a single path entry, validating it"""
        folder_or_file, _, self.path = self.path.partition("/")
        if not ZipRelPath.FILE_NAME_RE.match(folder_or_file):
            raise ValueError(u"'%s' is not a valid file or folder name" % folder_or_file)
        if self.path:
            self.folders.append(folder_or_file)
        else:
            self.file_name = folder_or_file

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"ZipRelPath [lang-tag: %s, folders: %s, file_name: %s" % (self.lang_tag, self.folders, self.file_name)
```

And a short set of tests:

```
GOOD = [
    "$%'-_@~()&+,=[].txt9",
    "my/path/to/file.txt",
    "locales/en/file.txt",
    "locales/en-us/file.txt",
    "locales/en-us-abc123-xyz/file.txt",
    "locales/abcdefgh-12345678/file.txt",
    "locales/en/my/path/to/file.txt",
    u"my\u00A5\u0160\u039E\u04FE\u069E\u0BCC\uFFFD/path/to/file.txt"
]
BAD   = [
    "",
    "/starts/with/slash",
    "bad^file",
    "locales//bad/locale",
    "locales/en123/bad/locale",
    "locales/EN/bad/locale",
    "locales/en-US/bad/locale",
    ]

for path in GOOD:
    print unicode(ZipRelPath(path))

for path in BAD:
    try:
        zip = ZipRelPath(path)
        raise Exception("Illegal path {0} was accepted by {1}".format(path, zip))
    except ValueError as exception:
        print "Incorrect path '{0}' fails with: {1}".format(path, exception)
```

Which produces:

```
ZipRelPath [lang-tag: None, folders: [], file_name: $%'-_@~()&+,=[].txt9
ZipRelPath [lang-tag: None, folders: ['my', 'path', 'to'], file_name: file.txt
ZipRelPath [lang-tag: en, folders: [], file_name: file.txt
ZipRelPath [lang-tag: en-us, folders: [], file_name: file.txt
ZipRelPath [lang-tag: en-us-abc123-xyz, folders: [], file_name: file.txt
ZipRelPath [lang-tag: abcdefgh-12345678, folders: [], file_name: file.txt
ZipRelPath [lang-tag: en, folders: ['my', 'path', 'to'], file_name: file.txt
ZipRelPath [lang-tag: None, folders: [u'my\xa5\u0160\u039e\u04fe\u069e\u0bcc\ufffd', u'path', u'to'], file_name: file.txt
Incorrect path '' fails with: Missing folder or file name
Incorrect path '/starts/with/slash' fails with: '' is not a valid file or folder name
Incorrect path 'bad^file' fails with: 'bad^file' is not a valid file or folder name
Incorrect path 'locales//bad/locale' fails with: '' is not a valid language tag
Incorrect path 'locales/en123/bad/locale' fails with: 'en123' is not a valid language tag
Incorrect path 'locales/EN/bad/locale' fails with: 'EN' is not a valid language tag
Incorrect path 'locales/en-US/bad/locale' fails with: 'en-US' is not a valid language tag
```

Please let me know if any of your test cases fail, and I'll see if I can fix it.

Comment: I get this:
    `Traceback (most recent call last):`

    `File "./packaging.py", line 141, in <module> test_wgt(wgtfile)`
    `File "./packaging.py", line 101, in test_wgt`
     `raise Exception("Illegal path {0} was accepted by {1}".format(info.filename, zip))`
     `Exception: Illegal path config.xml was accepted by <ZipRelPath.ZipRelPath instance at 0xb73ea70c>`

Comment: Looks like the parser accepted as valid a path that your test considers as invalid. Can you share the test case, specifically the path? It would be really helpful to get the whole set of tests (if that is possible).

Comment: My bad I run the tests without unicode(), now works like a charm thanks a lot.

Comment: That's great to hear - you had me worried for a couple of minutes ;)

Answer (score 2):

You should probably try [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/). Here is a [quick example](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/ebnf.py) from pyparsing website which you can easily modify to suit your purpose.

Comment: I didn't managed to make it work, can you give an example of what you mean by "easily modified"?

Comment: If you are familiar with `yacc` you should also consider [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/), although `pyparsing` looks quite similar.

Comment: @TerjeR I don't know if it deserve to make a parser only for this rules, I guess pretty much of it is translatable, I don't get `lang-tag` for example...

Comment: `lang-tag` is just a production from a non-terminal (`lang-tag`) to a mix of terminals and non-terminals. You should read up on [EBNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus–Naur_Form). It's sort of like regex (if you are familiar with that), except the [regularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

Comment: @TerjeR I am familiar with regex if you want to give an example in this case I just discovered that much of the rules above is to test for utf8